# Is there a Google App Scripts sheets event fired when a collaborative user makes an amendment

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

One nice feature of Google sheets is that two users can use the sheet at once.

If I am editing the sheet myself, using Google App Scripts (GAS) an onEdit event is fired when I make a change to a cell.

If I have the sheet open by two different users, is there a way to detect a change made by someone else?  I would like to keep the Google app script code up to date without having to constantly poll the sheet to check if anyone else has made an amendment.

I have the following as my onEdit code, this puts up a simple alert when something is edited.

```
function onEdit(){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert('Edited');
}
```

This fires only on the user that made the change and not the other user looking at the spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using [simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite), it should be triggered immaterial of who is using the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmm, I will need to investigate - when I tested earlier with onEdit and onChange only the user doing the change fired the alert. I will retest though thank you

Comment: There is, of course, a caveat, simple triggers cannot run services that require authorization. So, I would suggest you show us your onEdit code or at least explain what your code does when someone edits the document.

Comment: I have added my onEdit code, this is very simple at the moment i'm just trying to get the code to execute.

Comment: A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open editor, and only if the script is container-bound to the editor. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Comment: Ahhh, so it’s because I’m trying to show an alert it’s not appearing to be working, but it is actually firing on both? What I actually want to do is update my sidebar, thinking about this, is this even possible to call a method on the sidebar from the GAS code behind?

Comment: It is not firing on both! onEdit trigger only fires for the user making the change, hence only that user gets the edited prompt

Comment: Change your function name to `myOnEdit` and install it. It should fire regardless of who made the edit, as the function will always run as if you made the edit yourself.

Comment: I've tried this but not sure if I am installing correctly?  I did this on script editor -> edit -> current project triggers -> add trigger -> add the myOnEdit trigger to the onEdit event type... this however still only showed the UI edited box on the current users page and not the other users?

Comment: It didn't work for me either. I used this code `function myOnEdit(e) {
  var rgA1=e.range.getA1Notation();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Utilities.formatString('%s has been edited', rgA1));
}`  Used this to create trigger `function createMyOnEditTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit').forSpreadsheet('SSID').onEdit().create()
}`

Comment: So do we think this is indeed not possible?

Comment: @user Instead of a alert, try saving the edit to a separate sheet (say log sheet). You can visit that sheet to see latest changes.

Comment: @Cooper It seems I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Logging to a separate spreadsheet is not the same thing. As this will just be firing on the user that did it not both users. I am thinking what I am after cannot be done unfortunately!